# BlockingCollection.Add() - Why does the documentation say that it MAY block?

Tags: c#, .net

[The documentation for BlockingCollection.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.add?view=net-5.0) (under "Remarks") says:

> If a bounded capacity was specified when this instance of
> BlockingCollection was initialized, a call to Add may block until
> space is available to store the provided item.

What would cause it *not* to block even if space is not available?

Comment: I don't think that's what it's saying. I think it's saying that if space is not available, Add will block until it is. If a bounded capacity was specified, Add may block, because space may not be available

Comment: @canton7 You might be right. If so, I think the documentation should be clearer about that.

Comment: You can raise a documentation issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues), I think (there used to be a link somewhere on the docs page, but I can't see it now...). In my experience they're pretty good at addressing issues

Comment: @canton7 Thanks. Though I'm still not _sure_ it's an error (though it seems so).

Comment: I think it's just slightly ambiguous wording -- English is hard

Comment: At least for core, it doesn't seem to be ambiguous.  It can block or not block depending on the state.  It may have to spin while it waits for other threads adding something to the collection. If there's space and no one adding it's not going to block at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence in the documentation can be understood in two ways, either that it may block until there's space (but it might also not block despite there not being space) - the way I understood it initially, or it might mean that it might block because there might not be enough space (in which case it will always block) - as suggested in the comments.

Since the second reading makes more sense, I'll assume it's the correct one. However, I'm leaving this here. Someone else might be mislead by the docs as I've been, and this might help them.